# Spring Boot + JWT: should tokens be checked against auth server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

As I understand a JWT contains a header, a payload and a signature.

The signature ensures the JWT integrity by encrypting the header and the payload with a secret.

Consequently, if the authentication (token) server and a resource server share the same secret the resource server should be able to validate the token by himself, and that's the purpose of these tokens.

Consequently I have two questions:

- why does Spring provides a `RemoteTokenServices`, isn't it an anti-pattern ?

[EDIT] Answered this one myself:

> In fact, the main issue using JWT without checking them against a token store is that we cannot revoke them. Using only the signature to check its authenticity, any token stays valid until it expires.
>
> Checking the JWT against a token store allows us to revoke tokens and in this case, a valid JWT that has been revoked won't be accepted to authenticate a request.
>
> Consequently, the only case it can be safe to use self-authenticating JWT is with very short expiration times.

- if I don't use this service, how can I achieve the token validation locally using only the secret ?

My current config of a resource server consulting a remote token service:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Profile("!test")
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${auth-server.url}")
    private String authEndpoint;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("ms/legacy");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().cors().disable().csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(
            (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
        .accessDeniedHandler(
            (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));
  }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("ms/legacy");
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setClientId(clientId);
        tokenServices.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(authEndpoint + "/uaa/oauth/check_token");
        return tokenServices;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - why does Spring provides a RemoteTokenServices, isn't it an anti-pattern ?

Spring is a flexible framework that will offer to you different implementations 
 , it give you the choice to choose what the best implementation to fit your needs

> - if I don't use this service, how can I achieve the token validation locally using only the secret ?

token validation locally :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {   

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
    }
```